# WebFilter is not reached

Tags: servlets, filter

I've created this filter:

```java
@WebFilter(
    dispatcherTypes = { DispatcherType.REQUEST },
    urlPatterns = { "/authz/*" },
    initParams = { @WebInitParam(name = "excludedPaths", value = "authorize, token, log") }
)
public class BearerFilter implements Filter
{
```

`BearerFilter` code is never reached. However, if I set `urlPatterns = { "/*" }`, `doFilter` code is reached.

Obviously, I'm making calls to that on using this URL:

```
http://guest1:8080/authz/cmng/client
```

Comment: Filters are relative to the application context. Is the application deployed at `/` or at `/authz`?

Comment: Yes, the application is deployed on `authz`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter URL patterns are **relative** to the *application context*.

---

> The application is deployed on `authz`

So a filter URL pattern such as `/authz/*` won't work for you.

> I'm making calls to that on using this URL:
>
> ```
> http://guest1:8080/authz/cmng/client
> ```

The filter should be mapped to the paths that come *after* `/authz`, such as `/cmng`, `/cmng/*`, `/cmng/client`, `/cmng/client/*` and so on.

And the pattern `/*` can be used to catch all requests the hit your application.